# Mysql where clause combining

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

I want to get all records EXCEPT Car with id 1, and Car with id 2.

So I need Car 3 and Bus 1 in this case.

I wrote this query:

```
select * from table

where
(

(topable_type != 'Car' AND topable_id != 1)

OR

(topable_type != 'Car' AND topable_id != 2)

)
```

But this returns me zero records when I need two of them.

Looks like this query completely ignores all parentheses, and just filters out EVERYTHING with type Car or id 1 or 2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when `topable_type = 'car'` and `topable_id = 2` is `true`, the condition `topable_type != 'Car' AND topable_id != 1` matches and the record is selected.

If you don't want cars with id 1 and 2, you can use the operator `NOT` on the clause that would select them, such as :

```
WHERE NOT (
    -- Check the equality operators
    --            |                      |
    --            v                      v
    (topable_type = 'Car' AND topable_id = 1)
    OR 
    (topable_type = 'Car' AND topable_id = 2)
)
```

---

Your condition could be refactored to something like

```
WHERE NOT (topable_type = 'Car' AND (topable_id = 1 OR topable_id = 2))
```

Or eventually

```
WHERE NOT (topable_type = 'Car' AND topable_id IN (1, 2))
```

But this is another topic

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
select * from table
where topable_id NOT IN (
  -- and here subquery to find IDs which you don't need
  select topable_id from table
  where topable_type = 'Car' AND topable_id IN [1, 2]
)
```